# Value visibility

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

I am currently reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* and there is something that I can't understand.

```
public class NoVisibility {
private static boolean ready;
private static int number;
private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
public void run() {
while (!ready)
Thread.yield();
System.out.println(number);
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
new ReaderThread().start();
number = 42;
ready = true;
}
}
```

and the author says

> NoVisibility could loop forever because the value of ready might never become
>   visible to the reader thread.

And there is no explanation or maybe it is somewhere later, but for now I am really confused. I would really appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This means that

```
while (!ready)
    Thread.yield();
```

will run forever because,
Setting ready to true in the main method won't reflect in the thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ReaderThread().start();
    number = 42;
    ready = true;
}
```

Instead you can use the term **volatile** which will update the value of when there is a change in the variable.

Comment: Yea i know that, but why? Why setting ready to true won't reflect in another thread?

Comment: Because values are cached. It's very expensive to always fetch the value from main memory, therefore you need to explicitly "share" the value, whether by using a volatile field, synchronized block or other mechanism.

Comment: Correct, you can find more on this at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html.